# Difference between assigning a pointer and using strcpy

Tags: c++, c, pointers, malloc

I am given the following code:

```
char buffer[100];

int main()
{
   strcpy( buffer, "on the footsteps of dawn" );

     char *s = buffer;

   printf( "After assignment, s is:\n\t%s\n", s ); // prints out "on the footsteps of dawn"

   strcat( s, "... who's never ever been born" );

   printf( "\nAfter modifying s, it is:\n\t%s\n", s );  
   printf( "But buffer is:\n\t%s\n", buffer );        //both print out "on the footsteps of dawn...who's never ever been born" 

   //now trying to do the same thing differently
   strcpy( buffer, "on the footsteps of dawn" );

   s = (char*) malloc( 100 );
   strcpy( s, buffer );
   strcat( s, "... who's never ever been born" );

   printf( "After modifying s, it is:\n\t%s\n", s );  // "on the footsteps of dawn...who's never ever been born" 
   printf( "But buffer is:\n\t%s\n", buffer ); // "on the footsteps of dawn"
```

So the question I have is WHY on the second try, after modifying s, buffer stayed the same. I see that s was assigned  two different ways, and know that it would be the case, but I want to know how exactly malloc() works.
Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried looking up for yourself how `malloc` works..? It's pretty well documented.

Comment: Are you sure that you have used the size argument in malloc() correctly? i.e. are you sure 100 is all you need? Sounds like you are missing out after having 100 bytes. Why don't you printout the size of *s and see how big that actually is with the full string?

Comment: i don't see what the code snippet has to do with how malloc works. you could use two different static buffers and still get the same behaviour

Comment: @hagubear: If you want to copy a 100-byte `char` array, then having `malloc()` allocate 100 bytes for it is perfectly fine.

Comment: Indeed I read info about malloc()! But it made everything more confusing. If at first I had an answer that malloc() creates a separate pointer that has nothing to do with buffer, but after I read more about this topic, I was in great doubt

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char buffer[100];

int main( void )
{
    strcpy( buffer, "on the footsteps of dawn" );

    char *s = buffer;

    printf( "buffer = %p, s = %p\n", buffer, s );

    return 0;
}
```

If you run it you will get that the printf outputs the same value two times. For example in my computer I got

```
buffer = 0x80497e0, s = 0x80497e0
```

So in this case s is simply an alias of buffer. It points to the same extent of memory where the buffer is allocated.

In the second case of your program when you wrote

```
s = (char*) malloc( 100 );
strcpy( s, buffer );
strcat( s, "... who's never ever been born" );
```

s points to a different extent of memory that was explicitly allocated in the heap. Statement

```
strcpy( s, buffer );
```

copied the content of buffer in the new area.

However the next statement

```
strcat( s, "... who's never ever been born" );
```

does not influence on buffer. It changes a different extent of memory so buffer will be the same as before using the statement..

Comment: The keyword here is `alias` :)

Answer (score 2):

It's because `s` is no longer pointing to `buffer`, it is now pointing to the beginning of the chunk of memory that was returned by `malloc`.

For more information on `malloc`, you can look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/).

Answer (score 2):

Kate, malloc() is giving you a new pointer to some other area of memory (that has nothing to do with 'buffer') and assigning that pointer to 's'.  Now 's' points at one spot in memory and 'buffer' points at another.

The strcpy() is taking the characters from the block of memory called 'buffer' and copying them to the block of memory now called 's'.  's' and 'buffer' are two separate spots in memory that happen to have the same characters.

The strcat() adds on to the string pointed to be 's'.  The string pointed to by 'buffer' does not change.  Remember, they are two separate areas of memory that happen to have the same thing.

In your first case 's' and 'buffer' were pointing to the same memory, so filling that memory with different 'stuff' was visible through both variables.

+1 for great taste in music!

Answer (score 0):

`malloc` returns a pointer to new, allocated memory (if successful). You copy then and `strcat` to this new memory

```
s = (char*) malloc( 100 );
strcpy( s, buffer );
strcat( s, "... who's never ever been born" );
```

which doesn't affect `buffer` in anyway.